# how do I connect cpanel with RESTful API?

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova, rest

short stories like this, I have a server to use cpanel to remotely.

after that I want create a web page that can auto installer blog or other cms. (like: wordpress cms)

The biggest problem is can I can connect to the web my cpanel? then from cpanel directly execute orders that have been granted to its servers.

as far as I know, can use the REST API or something. maybe friends here who can give the right solution or comments in order to face these problems.

Comment: If cPanel has such a REST APi it would be in their docs

Comment: thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I Know, Cpanel has no relate with RESTfull API. As you can upload the web file and can Access it correctly, You Should can do anything with your RESTfull API. The limit is only the sky~

Keep Going Brother!

Comment: Answers and questions should only be in english here. I have removed the text of other language

Answer (score 0):

To connect with cpanel using cpanel api is very easy. 
you will be needed cpanel username , password and cpanel login domain. and below is the way to connect with cpanel api

include main file for cpanel api connection, which can be download from here:- https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+cPanel+API+2

```
        require_once '../components/xmlapi.php';

        $xmlapi = new \xmlapi($domain);
        //checking authentication of the cpanel
        $xmlapi->password_auth($username,$password);

        $xmlapi->set_port(21);

        $result = $xmlapi->api1_query(password, 'CustInfo', 'getemail', array());
```